# Percentage not available in Highcharts Pie Legend - Issue #897 - v3.0.2

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to get the percentage value for the point in a pie chart to show in the legend. I can't simply use the this.y value because my values do not add up to 100 like in many of the examples out there. The percentage is a calculation of the totals for each point.

I noticed in a recent post that the issue has been resolved and has been closed. I looked at the source code and did notice the new code.

So I downloaded the Highcharts 3.0.2 source code and updated my source code to reference it, but I cannot find that updated code in the source. It shows it there in 3.0.2 in GitHub, but it's missing in 3.0.2 in the package from the website.

Is there a source version available that has this update properly applied? I don't want to have to manually add it like I did by merging the GitHub version with the Zip from Highcharts.com.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at thread https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/897.

Correct percetange is available in the master branch

http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.src.js